# mac excel 2011 vba range gives error

Tags: excel, vba, macos

im using excel mac 2011. Im trying to get the contents in cell A2, but it prompts an error. Getting the contents of cell A1 works, but not A2. I also notice there is no problem with the same code running in PC excel.

My vba code is as follows:

```
msgbox Range("A2")
```

I have also tried:

```
msgbox Range("A2").value
msgbox Cells(2,1)
```

but nothing works on mac. i receive this error message:

[image]

I have even updated my excel to ver 14.3.9 but it doesn't works.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I'd bet that the contents of the cell is really long. Try limiting the msgbox string to the first 100 characters and see if that helps.

Comment: No, it only contains a dummy text for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like some weird macness to me. According to this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2624782

that particular error can occur if you have your region in your Mac's system settings set to something other than the US. Sounds pretty strange. I do not have a mac to test on, but try to adjust your region settings and see if that fixes it. Googling the error codes of 80000008 and -2147483640 yield several unrelated situations that seem to all have some resolution involving region settings.

Comment: Hi, that's the magic! it Works after setting the region format to US. Thanks so much!